# Is there an easy way to toggle logging on/off in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, comments

I have logging lines of code throughout my application, but it's a pain in the ass to go through the entire file and comment out/uncomment every line that I need to log.  Outside of wrapping each and every one in "#if debug then" statements and either building in release or debug, I haven't found an easy way to just toggle these lines to be either commented or uncommented (or any other option that would accomplish my goal).  Are there any good options available?

Answer (score 0):

Use a configurable logging framework like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/).  Otherwise, you could create a common logging method and decorate it with [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g.

```
Module DebugModule

    <Conditional("DEBUG")> _
    Public Sub DebugMsg(ByVal message As String)
        Debug.Print(Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff ") & message)
    End Sub

End Module

DebugMsg("Message goes here")
```

In this case, calls to `DebugMsg` will only be included in when the DEBUG symbol is defined.